# Old FreeNAS server shutdowns every day after being moved. Why?

Tags: hardware-failure, power, shutdown, freenas, file-server

This is probably something obvious, but I have an old HP machine that we've been using for 9 years as a file server (it uses FreeNAS 9.2). It's been working fine, but I recently moved it to another location in our building and now it shuts down every day by itself between 3 and 5 am. We've changed the UPS, changed the port on the UPS, changed the power cable itself, but it always seems to shut down anyway. Perhaps I joggled something loose when carrying it, but then why does it shut down every day around the same time and not randomly?

Do any of you experienced sysadmins have an idea of what could be wrong?

Comment: Have you checked if the UPS actually works in case of power loss? It could be that it doesn't switch to battery fast enough.

Comment: @gronostaj That's a good idea, but the other servers plugged into the UPS don't seem to shown any sign of shutting down.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart Sorry to be a n00b, but which logs? It's FreeBSD based.

Comment: (**/var/log/messages**) there should be some other logs in that folder that will give you some indication if it's software related. If it's a hardware crash it may not get written to a log before it shuts down though.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart Thank you for clarifying! Unfortunately, FreeNAS 9.2 wipes all those kinds of files out at every boot it seems. The log starts at the reboot and has no info from before.

Comment: You running this on a USB? I don't think that's normal behavior, I've been running freenas for a long time and the only time I've ever seen that is with wonkey OS installations. You are probably going to have to add more info to the question, what is it running on, how it's installed to the machine. I think there is a way to get it to write those logs to external disks